# og meta tags are not working for whatsapp

Tags: php, html, meta-tags, whatsapp

I have added meta tags to my web page, those are working for one page and not working for another page.

Meta tags working for this page, when share link url on whatsapp

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Indian Heart Journal now available online: A must read">
<meta property="og:description" content=".. One of the best rated journals for Cardiologists in Asia">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://therightdoctors.com/the-interview/dr-mk-das-consultant-cardiologist-indian-heart-journal-now-available-online-a-must-read">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="@therightdoctors">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://storage.googleapis.com/web-assets/images/IHJ_images/Dr.MKDas2/Dr.MKDas2-large.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://storage.googleapis.com/web-assets/images/IHJ_images/Dr.MKDas2/Dr.MKDas2-large.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="500">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="400">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
```

Like same as above I added meta tags for another page, but these are not working when share link url on whatsapp.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Highlights of BIG BP Survey - Hyderabad">
<meta property="og:description" content="BIG BP Survey - Hyderabad.  ">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://therightdoctors.com/highlights/big-bp-survey-hyderabad">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="@therightdoctors">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://storage.googleapis.com/web-assets/videos/event/cardiacprevent2015/big-india-bp-survey/video%20frames/hyderabad.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://storage.googleapis.com/web-assets/videos/event/cardiacprevent2015/big-india-bp-survey/video%20frames/hyderabad.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="500">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="400">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
```

Please help me, where I'm doing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

They will work, it's just that when you paste the complete link (including the http[s] part), you will need to wait for a few seconds to fetch the description.